# how to take value from grid view and stores into text box ,on a template button event?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a form for saving Medium details, columns are, MID,MediumName,CreationDate,Status.I have bind full table in a gridview name gvmedium, i am having a textbox on the form .I want to fill the text box from grid views value of column MediumName on the template button click event.can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CommandName and Command Argument to achieve it and on Code Behind use `RowCommand` event.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResetPassword" Text="Reset Password" runat="server" CommandName="ResetPassword" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("UserId") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

and then do  your work here

```
 protected void grdUserGroupList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "ResetPassword")
            {
               GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
               int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex; 
               lblMId.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
               txtMedium.Text=gvMedium.Rows[RowIndex ].Cells[0].Text; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I wanted to insert the value in text box on button's which is inside the grid view click event and that grid view is binded to the database table..can u assist me to do that?

Comment: Can Anyone help me with above problem

Comment: I have given you an example with `linkbutton` click. what's the problem in this?

Comment: MY CS page is :
 protected void gvMedium_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "gvbtnUpdate")
            {
                lblMId.Visible = true;
                lblMId.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                       
                
                                    
                    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    
                    
                    txtMedium.Text=gvMedium.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;

                 
                }

Comment: I think you are passing wrong value in index. I have updated my answer so take a look into that